# Vector Space and Parametric Vector Form

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Either use an appropriate theorem to show that the given set, W, is a vector space or find a specific example to the contrary.

$\left( \begin{bmatrix} a\\b\\c\\d \end{bmatrix} \begin{align} & a-2b=4c\\ &3a=c+3d\end{align}\right)$

I put the equation on the right into a matrix as follows

$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & -2 & -4 & 0 & 0 \\ -2 & 0 &1 & 3 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$

$\text{RREF} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & -\frac{1}{2} & -\frac{3}{2} &0 \\ 0 & 1 & \frac{7}{4} & -\frac{3}{4} &0 \end{bmatrix}$

Then do reduced echelon form and write my answer in a parametric vector form.

$\begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\x_3\\x_4 \end{bmatrix} = x_3 \begin{bmatrix} \frac{1}{2} \\ -\frac{7}{4} \\1 \\0\end{bmatrix} + x_4 \begin{bmatrix} \frac{3}{2} \\ \frac{3}{4} \\0 \\1\end{bmatrix} $

Is this a correct way to approach this problem? I'm just confused by about what the problem is asking exactly. This means that $x_3$ maps to the zero vector and indeed this is a vector space?

Did I write my answer in correct parametric vector form?

Comment: It is perhaps easier to show that $W$ satisfies the axioms of a subspace (of the vector space $K^4$). If $x,y\in W$, then $x+y\in W$, for example.

Comment: I just updated my answer. I realized I was missing a column. Okay. I will attempt that. Thank you.